# Why does my DNS MX query return an SOA record?

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell

I am using PowerShell to get an array of MX records. I am wondering why the following command would return SOA records as I have specified MX for the type parameter.

```
Resolve-DnsName $SomeDomainName -type MX -Server 8.8.8.8 -DnsOnly -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: No MX record exists for the domain in question.

Comment: The SOA record would be in the `authority` section, not the `answer` section. It is normal for the SOA record to be there when there are zero answers. ([RFC 2308](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2308))

Comment: One of you want to submit the answer so we can close out the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is almost certainly just a negative response.

There are two types of "not found" responses, there's `NXDOMAIN` and `NODATA`.

- `NXDOMAIN` means that the *name* requested in the query does not exist at all.
  This type of response has status `NXDOMAIN` and the relevant `SOA` record in the `AUTHORITY` section (nothing in the `ANSWER` section).
- `NODATA` means that the *name* requested in the query does exist, but that there are no records of the requested *type* for that name.
  This type of response has status `NOERROR` (it doesn't have a status of its own) and has the relevant `SOA` record in the `AUTHORITY` section (nothing in the `ANSWER` section).

I had a quick look at `Resolve-DnsName` and my impression is that its inconsistent behavior does nothing to help your understanding of what is going on.
In the case of an `NXDOMAIN` response it throws an error, but in the case of a `NODATA` response it returns the response as if it was a success. This just seems strange, those two types of responses are similar failure modes but for whatever reason they are treated entirely differently by `Resolve-DnsName`.

For easier understanding of what is happening I would suggest spending a moment with `dig`, so that you can see the full responses for both these cases.